# Pass a php var to javascript with the value of the variable at the time in a loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have this problem . I change to a javascript php variable, but the variable that I have to go is inside a loop , and, of course , it always passes the last value ! How can I make that exceeded the value of the variable at that time ? this is the code !

```
for ($ a = 0 ; $ a < 2 ; $ a = $ a + 1 ) {
? >
< TD >
< Script >
var step = " name < ? php echo $ rigauno- ? > ; ? > " ;
< / Script >
< Button type = "button " onclick = " funzionepassaggio (step ) "  class = " btn btn btn -info - lg " data- Toggle = " modal " data- target = " # ModalSubmit " > < ? Php echo " empty " ? ; ? > < / Button >
< / TD >
< ? Php } ? >
```

Comment: are you sure this is the code? there are a lot of spaces out there that shouldn't be.. `$ a =`, `< Scr`, `< ?`, and .. everything else

Comment: and please guys - STOP using inline expressions!

Answer (score 0):

Use different names for the variables or use an array.

The PHP will execute completely before any javascript will run, so as 'step' is being repeatedly declared in the same scope, you are overwriting the value of the variable 'step' multiple times.

This variable will always hold the last written value when the page is loaded.

I imagine you have a page with a different button for each step.

**Using different variable names**

```
var step<?php echo $a; ?> = //yourvalue

<Button type="button" onclick="funzionepassaggio(step<?php echo $a; ?>)" />
```

**Using an array**

declare the array outside of the php loop

```
var steps = new Array();
```

then inside the loop, push elements into the array

```
steps.push(<?php echo $a; ?>);
```

or

```
steps[<?php echo $a; ?>] = <?php echo $a; ?>;
```

then to retrieve the value

```
<Button type="button" onclick="funzionepassaggio(step[<?php echo $a; ?>])" />
```

Comment: still perform all the php and passed variable is always the last. With an array passes all values, but how to go back to the past? A big problem ....

Comment: The PHP will always run completely to the end before the page is loaded on the server side. Once the page is loaded, the Javascript will execute in the browser.